# CSS formatting showing in IE but not Chrome or Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

This one is stumping me, as I've searched and searched through similar issue topic threads on this site but none of them are helping me resolve the issue.

I have the following HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sprout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mysample</h1>
    <div class="hero">
        <h2>Sprout.</h2>
        <p>A book by J. Daniel Bedford</p>
        <a href="#">Read now.</a>
    </div>
    <p>&copy; Mystwood Publishers Limited</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and the below CSS file code in my main.css file in the same directory as my HTML file (C:\HTML)

```
h1 {
    font-family: Palatino, 'Palatino Linotype', serif;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 90px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

The text formatting works correctly when I open the code in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox, what might I be missing about these two browsers that could be causing the issue?

Comment: Does getting rid of the `./` in `./main.css` make any difference?

Comment: I think Grim is right (in some way I don't understand) - if you move your css into a Style section in your HTML file, then all works fine in all main browsers. This argues that the problem lies in the reference to the link css file. I've never used ./ - only relative paths, but it may be that different browsers interpret it differently - try using an absolute path to start with...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately removing the "./" did not help, it was suggested as a possible solution in a different thread from a while back and I had it in there from that attempt.

Comment: Trying referencing it with the root directory. Put a "/" first, and them all of the folder until you reach the CSS file. And if that doesn't work, try "../" instead of "./"

Comment: Tried that Kyle, no dice :( Frustrating that it works in IE and not the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presentation (css) can appear different in different web browsers because each web browser has their own default and user configurable settings. You will always see differences between browsers because of differences in the default settings. eg. In the screen shot below using your sample code you can see that on my computer IE and other browsers display the page 'more or less' the same.
[image: Canary v IE11]

To make browsers display the same web pages 'more or less the same' you need to configure each of them with the same default settings for presentation (fonts, font sizes, color, background colors etc)

To debug rendering differences between browsers you need to use the DOM Explorer tab of the Dev tool in each browser(screen shot above) and compare the applied rules.

**To help you further we would really need a screen shot from your computer**, showing the browsers side by side. As you can see by the screen shot on my computer different browsers display the page 'more or less the same'. That's because I have configure all of my test browsers with the same user settings for presentation/accessibility (text size, zoom, color, background-color, font family, link and hover color etc).

The best way to test between browsers is to use https://www.browserstack.com/ because you are using virtual instances of vendors' browsers that have the 'factory' default settings. Comparing browsers on your own computer you should expect that the best result is that they will display the same web page "more or less the same", but not exactly the same.

To debug presentation, you need to use the DOM Explorer tab of your browsers dev tool.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sprout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {
            font-family: Palatino, 'Palatino Linotype', serif;
            color: blue;
            font-size: 90px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 32px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mysample</h1>
    <div class="hero">
        <h2>Sprout.</h2>
        <p>A book by J. Daniel Bedford</p>
        <a href="#">Read now.</a>
    </div>
    <p>&copy; Mystwood Publishers Limited</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Modifying my browsers to use the same defaults as described above worked! Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

This also stumped me for a long time - Page looks okay in Edge\IE11 but not Chrome or Firefox. Eventually found there was nothing wrong with the HTML or CSS syntax. The fix was simple. The HTML file was encoded in UTF-16. I overwrote the file saving it as UTF-8. It now works fine in all four browsers.