# CSS not applying to all items of a class

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, css-selectors

I'm not a web developer by any means, but am designing a simple frontend for my application. The goal of the application is to display some data, and receive comments/approval status (both features will be implemented at a later date).

My issue:

For some reason, on IE (The only browser I have access to at work, and the browser my user(s) will be using) the table styles don't apply properly to all instances of the class. When I test this in IE and Edge, the tables have different styles applied, which hinders readability. Judging by current data from my Python code, there will be 177 variables total to describe between 67 pairs of (serial number, LTT name).

I've run this through a validator already, and received no errors. https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Based on the documentation I've read regarding CSS and class selectors, I see no reason why this shouldn't work. This has proven to be a much more frustrating task than it should have been.

Below are the CSS and HTML as on my PC:

```css
.outerContainer {
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
}

.detailData {
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-color: blue;
  /*cell-padding: 5px;
    */
}

.datahead {
  border-bottom-style: inset;
  border-bottom-color: blue;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This page is meant to be a place to test out layouts for when I actually have the tools to make my Python code
web-capable. Everything on here will be static example data, based on what I've seen in the output from my code.
-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Display Page</title>

  <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="U:\work\svn\change_analysis\web_stuff\testpage.css">
-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testpage.css">


  <!--<style>-->
  <!--table.detailData{-->
  <!--border-collapse: collapse;-->
  <!--tr {-->
  <!--padding: 2px;-->
  <!--text-align: center;-->
  <!--}-->
  <!--}-->

  <!--</style>-->

</head>

<body>
  tyudfyudrtu sdfgdfsg
  <script>
    /*
     * This TINY script manages the show/hide functionality per (sn, ltt name) entry on the page.
     * I intend to keep any and all JS on this page neat and TINY.
     */
    function showHide(index) {
      //index should be an integer or string
      //Based on index, we should be able to find the clicked button and desired table to show/hide

      var source = document.getElementById("sh-" + index)
      var target = document.getElementById("index-" + index)

      if (target.style.display === "none") {
        target.style.display = "block";
        //source.textContent = "Hide";
        source.textContent = "v";
      } else {
        target.style.display = "none";
        //source.textContent = "Show";
        source.textContent = ">";
      }
    }
  </script>

  <p>Serial Number, Table Name</p>

  <div class="outerContainer">
    <!--
        Outer container for grouping
        -->


    <span>
            A3231E0020
        </span>
    <br/>
    <span>
            ST038IA0-O2B0-30-2:TC44-DK-10000-0-99999-12-1.0038-1-100-1-400-200
        </span>

    <br/>
    <button onclick="showHide(0)" id="sh-0"> > </button>
    <br/>
    <div id="index-0" style="display: none;">
      <table class="detailData">
        <!--
            This table is for testing out layout of data for a single table modified by a single serial number.
            -->
        <thead class="datahead">
          <tr>
            <td>Variable Name</td>
            <td>Current Value</td>
            <td>Default Value</td>
            <td>Directional Threshold, units</td>
            <td>Change Date</td>
            <td>Number of cuts since change</td>
            <td>Contour Cut Since Change</td>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--
                        These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
                    -->
            Large Focus
          </td>
          <td>
            -2.5
          </td>
          <td>
            -1.5
          </td>
          <td>
            1 digits
          </td>
          <td>
            2018-04-07 13:12:02
          </td>
          <td>
            20
          </td>
          <td>
            565.86 meters
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--
                        These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
                    -->
            Small Reduced Power
          </td>
          <td>
            500
          </td>
          <td>
            600
          </td>
          <td>
            10 percent
          </td>
          <td>
            2018-04-25 09:47:32
          </td>
          <td>
            4
          </td>
          <td>
            373.88 meters
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
    <br/>

  </div>
  <div class="outerContainer">

    <div class="headerTbl">
      <span>A0000E1111</span>
      <br/>
      <span>CU100IA0-N2B0-30-2</span>

    </div>

    <button onclick="showHide(1)" id="sh-1"> > </button>
    <br/>
    <div id="index-1" style="display: none;">
      <table class="detailData">
        <!--
                This table is for testing out layout of data for a single table modified by a single serial number.
                -->
        <thead>
          <tr class=datahead>
            <td>Variable Name</td>
            <td>Current Value</td>
            <td>Default Value</td>
            <td>Directional Threshold, units</td>
            <td>Change Date</td>
            <td>Number of cuts since change</td>
            <td>Contour Cut Since Change</td>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--
                            These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
                        -->
            Large Focus
          </td>
          <td>
            -2.5
          </td>
          <td>
            -1.5
          </td>
          <td>
            1 digits
          </td>
          <td>
            2018-04-07 13:12:02
          </td>
          <td>
            20
          </td>
          <td>
            565.86 meters
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--
                            These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
                        -->
            Small Reduced Power
          </td>
          <td>
            500
          </td>
          <td>
            600
          </td>
          <td>
            10 percent
          </td>
          <td>
            2018-04-25 09:47:32
          </td>
          <td>
            4
          </td>
          <td>
            373.88 meters
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

(Thank you kindly)

Comment: I am sorry you are forced to use IE. That can cause a lot of problems

Comment: Do either of the browsers display it properly, or are they both wrong?

Comment: Both browsers display equally incorrectly. One issue I fixed immediately after posting was adding a word to the header of the second table, which evens the lengths out. This still leaves the issue of the thead styles not being applied.

Comment: Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592594/css-formatting-showing-in-ie-but-not-chrome-or-firefox), seems pretty similar.

Comment: It very well might just be that certain browsers display things slightly differently.

Comment: Despite it being blocked from accessing the network, I was able to open the local file in Firefox. Since editing the second table header to add a word, the lengths of the tables are now properly aligned, but the thead bottom border is still missing in al browsers I have access to.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I'm not very good with HTML either, so I don't know definitively, but from messing around it looks like your `.detailData` style is overriding the `.datahead` style. Maybe because you have a style within a style?

Comment: Wait I figured something out: As is the style is being applied to the `thead`. Just try adding `color: green;` to the style and you can see that. So something is up with the borders.

Comment: Thanks for finding that, this gives me more ways to explore the issue. I'll try experimenting some more.

Comment: Let me know if you find anything. I have been playing around with it and I can never get the border to show up, no matter what i do...

Comment: Reading more documentation on W3schools, I don't see either thead or tr as having a property for border-bottom-*, so I might be SOL. We'll see if I can't find a solution or workaround...

Comment: Is the table border collapsed? So, you can only apply border to TD, not THEAD nor TR. Maybe just change your CSS declaration to **.datahead td { /* settings */ }**

Comment: WAIT @user2985413 COME BACK I FIGURED IT OUT

Comment: @cubemaster Hello, is me. What news do you bring?

Comment: Putting it in answer form now. There are a few minor changes

Comment: @Trilby `border-collapse` default is `separate`, so I don't believe that to be the case here. I think I've tried your second suggestion, let me try it again..

Comment: Ooh, nice name change

Comment: There you go @Gigaflop, that should work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
    .outerContainer {
   width: 80%;
   padding-left: 5%;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-color: black;
 }

 .detailData {
   border-style: inset;
   border-width: 4px;
   border-color: blue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
  
 }

 .datahead{
   border-bottom-style: inset;
      border-bottom-color: blue;
      border-bottom-width: 2px;
   color: green;

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This page is meant to be a place to test out layouts for when I actually have the tools to make my Python code
web-capable. Everything on here will be static example data, based on what I've seen in the output from my code.
-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test Display Page</title>

  <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="U:\work\svn\change_analysis\web_stuff\testpage.css">
-->


  <!--<style>-->
  <!--table.detailData{-->
  <!--border-collapse: collapse;-->
  <!--tr {-->
  <!--padding: 2px;-->
  <!--text-align: center;-->
  <!--}-->
  <!--}-->

  <!--</style>-->

</head>

<body>
  tyudfyudrtu sdfgdfsg
  <script>
    /*
     * This TINY script manages the show/hide functionality per (sn, ltt name) entry on the page.
     * I intend to keep any and all JS on this page neat and TINY.
     */
    function showHide(index) {
      //index should be an integer or string
      //Based on index, we should be able to find the clicked button and desired table to show/hide

      var source = document.getElementById("sh-" + index)
      var target = document.getElementById("index-" + index)

      if (target.style.display === "none") {
        target.style.display = "block";
        //source.textContent = "Hide";
        source.textContent = "v";
      } else {
        target.style.display = "none";
        //source.textContent = "Show";
        source.textContent = ">";
      }
    }
  </script>

  <p>Serial Number, Table Name</p>

  <div class="outerContainer">
    <!--
        Outer container for grouping
        -->


    <span>
            A3231E0020
        </span>
    <br/>
    <span>
            ST038IA0-O2B0-30-2:TC44-DK-10000-0-99999-12-1.0038-1-100-1-400-200
        </span>

    <br/>
    <button onclick="showHide(0)" id="sh-0"> > </button>
    <br/>
    <div id="index-0" style="display: none;">
  <table class="detailData" rules = "groups" >
   <!--
    This table is for testing out layout of data for a single table modified by a single serial number.
    -->
   <thead>
     <tr class = "datahead">
    <th>Variable Name</th>
    <th>Current Value</th>
    <th>Default Value</th>
    <th>Directional Threshold, units</th>
    <th>Change Date</th>
    <th>Number of cuts since change</th>
    <th>Contour Cut Since Change</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
     <!--
        These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
       -->
     Large Focus
      </td>
      <td>
     -2.5
      </td>
      <td>
     -1.5
      </td>
      <td>
     1 digits
      </td>
      <td>
     2018-04-07 13:12:02
      </td>
      <td>
     20
      </td>
      <td>
     565.86 meters
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
     <!--
        These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
       -->
     Small Reduced Power
      </td>
      <td>
     500
      </td>
      <td>
     600
      </td>
      <td>
     10 percent
      </td>
      <td>
     2018-04-25 09:47:32
      </td>
      <td>
     4
      </td>
      <td>
     373.88 meters
      </td>
    </tr>
      </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br/>

  </div>
  <div class="outerContainer">

    <div class="headerTbl">
      <span>A0000E1111</span>
      <br/>
      <span>CU100IA0-N2B0-30-2</span>

    </div>

    <button onclick="showHide(1)" id="sh-1"> > </button>
    <br/>
    <div id="index-1" style="display: none;">
      <table class="detailData">
        <!--
                This table is for testing out layout of data for a single table modified by a single serial number.
                -->
        <thead>
          <tr class=datahead>
            <td>Variable Name</td>
            <td>Current Value</td>
            <td>Default Value</td>
            <td>Directional Threshold, units</td>
            <td>Change Date</td>
            <td>Number of cuts since change</td>
            <td>Contour Cut Since Change</td>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--
                            These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
                        -->
            Large Focus
          </td>
          <td>
            -2.5
          </td>
          <td>
            -1.5
          </td>
          <td>
            1 digits
          </td>
          <td>
            2018-04-07 13:12:02
          </td>
          <td>
            20
          </td>
          <td>
            565.86 meters
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--
                            These fields would be filled by a template engine in the later and final versions
                        -->
            Small Reduced Power
          </td>
          <td>
            500
          </td>
          <td>
            600
          </td>
          <td>
            10 percent
          </td>
          <td>
            2018-04-25 09:47:32
          </td>
          <td>
            4
          </td>
          <td>
            373.88 meters
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alright, there are a few changes here:

1. You need to collapse the border for the `.detailData` style. Tables can only have 1 border style at once, from what I can tell, and since you have two styles on your table that both define border, the first one takes over.
2. I also changed the `<td>` tags in your header to `<th>` tags, as those are meant for headers. Personal preference, but I think it looks nicer.

The big part is the border collapse thing.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use your exact solution, but the information showed me how I could. I put `border-collapse: collapse` on `.detailData{..}` while removing all of its other styles, and added a `tbody class=databody` element to the non-header elements. This allowed me to place borders around the `databody` and `datahead ` classes as I wished, and appears to have spaced the cells out nicely.

Comment: Glad i could help. Taught me a thing or two as well